# How to remove line that starts with + or - followed by empty space only

Tags: awk, sed, grep

Here is a file that contains:

```
+ 
- 
+ <>cow apple</>
- apple
+ ball
+ +
- -
+ -
- +
+ !
- 
- 
+ 
+ $
+ **
+ *
+ =
+ #
- ?
- ◊
+ ◊◊
- 
-
```

Expect output:

```
+ <>cow apple</>
- apple
+ ball
+ +
- -
+ -
- +
+ !
+ $
+ **
+ *
+ =
+ #
- ?
- ◊
+ ◊◊
```

How to remove line that starts with + or - followed by empty space only?

Here is code which gives expected result but better solution would be very helpful. Since I am running this cmd on large file and has to be accurate.

```
sed ‘/^[^[:alnum:]]* $/d’
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this `grep` with `-v` (inverse) option:

```bash
grep -v '^[-+][[:blank:]]*$' file
+ <>cow apple</>
- apple
+ ball
+ +
- -
+ -
- +
+ !
+ $
+ **
+ *
+ =
+ #
- ?
- ◊
+ ◊◊
```

Here:

- `^[-+][[:blank:]]*$`: Matches a line starting with `-` or `+` followed by 0 or more whitespaces till end.

Following `awk` or `sed` solutions would also work:

```bash
sed '/^[-+][[:blank:]]*$/d' file

awk '!/^[-+][[:blank:]]*$/' file
```

Answer (score 1):

```
grep '^[+-]\s\S' file
```

- `^` start of line anchor
- `[+-]` match on `+` or `-`
- `\s` match a whitespace
- `\S` match a non-whitespace